# In Linux, zip multiple directories in one named zip file

Tags: linux, zip

I have the following directories, I want to zip up into the same zip file. Can someone provide the correct syntax?

ie. zipping the following directories:

- */home/users/jlefler/files*
- */opt/software/reports/files*

into a zip file called *backup.zip*.

Answer (score 207):

try

```
zip -r backup.zip /home/users/jlefler/files /opt/software/reports/files
```

you can add more directories at the end of the command

Comment: No need to write `backup.zip`, it appends `.zip` automatically.

Comment: Thanks. So we have to give space between the directories?

Comment: Doesn't work with zip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93)